# python: How to monitor a variable ? Execute command when variable change

Tags: python

I have a class like this

```py
class WaveData(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
```

and create a data object, plot a figure

```py
wave = WaveData([[1, 2, 3], 
                 [7, 5, 6]])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure()
plot1, = fig.canvas.figure.subplots().plot(wave.data[0])
plot2, = fig.canvas.figure.subplots().plot(wave.data[1])
```

I hope when I change the wave value , plot will change synchronously

```py
wave.data[1]=[5,6,7] # hope figure change together
```

I try to add method `changedata` for `WaveData` class, but:

1. it need use global variable `fig` , maybe not reasonale (I can put fig as self attribute , but in fact , the fig also link other class object which not written in here)
2. I cannot change `fig` by changing data directly: `wave.data[1] =[5,6,7]`

```py
class WaveData(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def changedata(self,value,index):
        self.data[index]=value
        

        #-- change the plot index th plot data--#
        global plot1,plot2,fig
        plot1.set_ydata(self.data[1])
        plot2.set_ydata(self.data[2])
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        #-- change the plot index th plot data--#
```

I want to create a watcher to monitor `wave.data` value . When detecte the value change , execute some action

How to do?

Answer (score 0):

Right: plotting is not a dynamic or interactive process.  You started the right way, with an access method to change the wave form.  Now you have to re-plot and re-show the result ... which will possibly require closing the first plot manually, depending on the interface of your chosen drawing package (e.g. `matplotlib`).

To get a fully interactive experience, you may want to use an animation package, such as PyGame, where changes in the visual display are part of the package assumptions.

Comment: Can't we use the advantage of properties set or get here?

Comment: @mahesh Not easily no ... suppose you make a getter for `.data` ... then the user can still change the data using `.data[0][0]=100` ... so now you need to wrap the value you are returning to trap `__setitem__` etc (which must wrap the values it returns) etc etc.